# ReactJS state changes are not reflected in different sessions at the same time

Tags: javascript, typescript, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS,Typescript and Firebase to build a web app, in which one user will be able to monitor the changes and interactions with the UI of another user. Both users can see an identical view at the same time with a few images displayed. For example, any image clicked by User1 changes its border, which should be reflected in the UI of User2. 
This is doable with DOM, typescript and firebase alone, but with ReactJS I'm facing a lot of difficulties.

First question: 
Is it possible to update an already created and displayed component in ReactJS without using state or props?

From what I've seen so far, I'm assuming this is not possible. So,

Second question:
I'm trying to use states alone to achieve what I explained, but it seems that whenever User1 for example changes the state, the component displayed to User1 is re-rendering alone without the component of User2 being able to capture the change in the state to re-render. Both of the components are identical. 
I'm using Chrome and Firefox to run the app with the 2 users. Is there a way to achieve this with states and props alone?

I'm a beginner in this area. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you centralize state management with something like [redux](http://redux.js.org/), the application state ought to be representable as a single object. You ought to then be able to add some [redux middleware](https://medium.com/@meagle/understanding-87566abcfb7a) to the app to push any state changes to, say, Firebase, and then read back all changes *from* Firebase and push them into your store (via an action).

If you do prefer to update the component without changing props instead, there is a [forceUpdate method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate).

Comment: Thanks. It was doable with forceUpdate